# Is using a linked-list to make a circular queue more advantageous than using an array?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, linked-list, circular-buffer, circular-list

This is what I understand as a circular queue -

- You specify the size of the circular queue at the start.
- Enqueuing elements, once you reach the end of the queue, you can "circle" back and start using the first slot, provided it has been dequeued and so on.

The general advantage of using a linked-list over an array would be the fact that you can have it grow dynamically as needed without having to worry about re-appropriating new space and copying the elements. In this case, putting a limit on the size of the linked-list does not make sense. Why not just use a fixed size array instead?

And if you are not going to specify the size of the circular queue then what is the point of using a linked-list to implement it. And how & when would you "circle" back and start filling out the already dequeued slots?

Am I missing something here?